# ERROR in : Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'NgxMatColorPickerModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Getting this error while running build
ERROR in : Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'NgxMatColorPickerModule in /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/tickets_stg/workspace/node_modules/@angular-material-components/color-picker/angular-material-components-color-picker.d.ts

This is my module where i have imported NgxMatColorPickerModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TeamsComponent } from './teams/teams.component';
import { ConfigurationNavComponent } from './configuration-nav/configuration-nav.component';
import { ConfigMenuComponent } from './config-menu/config-menu.component';
import { ConfigurationRoutingModule } from './configurations-routing.module';
import { ConfigurationsComponent } from './configurations.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppMaterialModule } from 'src/app/app-material/app-material.module';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
import { RolesComponent } from './roles/roles.component';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';
import { WorkSpacesComponent } from './work-spaces/work-spaces.component';
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown-angular7';
import { AppVersionsComponent } from './app-versions/app-versions.component';
import { NgxMatDatetimePickerModule, NgxMatTimepickerModule,NgxMatNativeDateModule } from 'ngx-mat-datetime-picker';
import { IssueStatusesComponent } from './issue-statuses/issue-statuses.component';
import { IssuePrioritiesComponent } from './issue-priorities/issue-priorities.component';
import { MAT_COLOR_FORMATS, NgxMatColorPickerModule, NGX_MAT_COLOR_FORMATS } from '@angular-material-components/color-picker';
import { MailTemplatesComponent } from './mail-templates/mail-templates.component';
import { AccessControlComponent } from './access-control/access-control.component';
import { TicketCategoriesComponent } from './ticket-categories/ticket-categories.component';
import { SlaPoliciesComponent } from './sla-policies/sla-policies.component';
import { TicketReasonsComponent } from './ticket-reasons/ticket-reasons.component';
import { CKEditorModule } from 'ngx-ckeditor';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TeamsComponent,
    ConfigurationNavComponent, 
    ConfigMenuComponent,
    ConfigurationsComponent,
    RolesComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    WorkSpacesComponent,
    AppVersionsComponent,
    
IssueStatusesComponent,
    IssuePrioritiesComponent,
    MailTemplatesComponent,
    AccessControlComponent,
    TicketCategoriesComponent,
    SlaPoliciesComponent,
    TicketReasonsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    ConfigurationRoutingModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    NgMultiSelectDropDownModule,
    NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
    NgxMatTimepickerModule,
    NgxMatNativeDateModule,
    NgxMatColorPickerModule,
    CKEditorModule
  ],
  providers:[DatePipe,{ provide: MAT_COLOR_FORMATS, useValue: NGX_MAT_COLOR_FORMATS }]
})
export class ConfigurationsModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also on Angular 7 with Color Picker 2.0.2, and was getting that error. On ng serve after a file was changed and it was triggered to recompile the changes the import is working and the error is gone.

I think I found a solution: I changed the import path to the bundles file:

```
import { MAT_COLOR_FORMATS, NgxMatColorPickerModule, NGX_MAT_COLOR_FORMATS } from '@angular-material-components/color-picker/bundles/angular-material-components-color-picker.umd';
```

Everything else stays the same.

Then the compile error disappears and everything works just fine.

Edit:

never mind. For non prod build this works find until you try to build the application ... we now moved to the default color picker of the browsers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated Please read the answer more carefully. While it may have been badly delivered, this ***does attempt*** to answer the question

Comment: @Tomerikoo It was edited, which really annoys me.